# Biblatex Harvard style ommit author in some citations

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style

## Problem

I am writting a paper where I mostly analize 2 papers written by different authors on different years and I am using a couple of other sources. Citations are done via `\textcite` or `\parencite` commands using biblatex. I want to ommit the author in these in text citations for the main papers, but not affect the rest of the bibliographic entries.

## Example

Instead of

> The author mentions, that it is hard to find an example (Author, 2009, p.83). However, another mentions, that it can be even more difficult (Author2, 2008, p.77).

I want

> The author mentions, that it is hard to find an example (2009, p.83). However, another mentions, that it can be even more difficult (2008, p.77).

I think as long as I do not include more papers in this naming scheme, it might be okay? What others have to say about it? However, in the bibliography list, I want the author fields to be present (i.e. unchanged).

## Question

Does anybody know if there is an elegant way of doing it? Maybe there is some general way of customizing particular entries using biblatex?

Comment: It depends on the style, but with the standard ones you can override all or part of the citation label with the `shorthand` or `label` fields. [This previous post provides](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49255) some details.

Comment: Maybe I am too thick to understand, but how can I use the shorthands to ommit the Author field only in the in text citations? I am not very familiar with the use of shorthands....

Comment: `shorthand` is a field you add to the `bib` file. It overrides the whole citation label. Referring to your two main papers only by year is a little ambiguous, but  you can do this by clearing the `labelname` list. Again, the answer depends on your style (`authoryear`?) and exactly what output you're wanting to achieve. You should add an example to your question to clarify all this.

Comment: sorry for not adding a specific example, hope, that you find the above helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to suppress `labelname` in citations. The hook

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearname{labelname}}
```

will delete the `labelname` list in every citation, but styles typically resort to printing fallback values. The `authoryear` style, for example prints the `labeltitle` field when `labelname` is unavailable. Suppressing all fallback values often results in spurious whitespace or punctuation.

One easy way around all this is to save `labelyear` into the `shorthand` field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{citeyear}
\addtocategory{citeyear}{companion,knuth:ct:a}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifcategory{citeyear}
    {\edef\cbxlabel{\thefield{labelyear}}%
     \restorefield{shorthand}{\cbxlabel}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite[10--11]{companion} showed that...
Filler \parencite[e.g.][10--15]{knuth:ct:a}.
Filler \textcite[10--11]{kant:ku}.
Filler \parencite[e.g.][10--15]{kant:kpv}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the `labelname` still appears in `\textcite`. This is intentional. `\textcite` is analogous to `\citeasnoun` in the Harvard styles. Suppressing `labelname` in `\textcite` would be like omitting the noun in `\citeasnoun`. It makes no sense.

`labelyear` isn't a very meaningful citation label. So I would recommend using a shorthand based on the title or authors of the work. The above document cites two entries with shorthands from `biblatex-examples.bib`. Here's an excerpt from this file.

```
@inbook{kant:kpv,
  shorthand = {KpV},
  author = {Kant, Immanuel},
  title = {Kritik der praktischen Vernunft},
  shorttitle = {Kritik der praktischen Vernunft},
  booktitle = {Kritik der praktischen Vernunft. Kritik der Urtheilskraft},
  maintitle = {Kants Werke. Akademie Textausgabe},
  volume = {5},
  publisher = {Walter de Gruyter},
  location = {Berlin},
  date = {1968},
  pages = {1--163},
}
@inbook{kant:ku,
  shorthand = {KU},
  author = {Kant, Immanuel},
  title = {Kritik der Urtheilskraft},
  booktitle = {Kritik der praktischen Vernunft. Kritik der Urtheilskraft},
  maintitle = {Kants Werke. Akademie Textausgabe},
  volume = {5},
  publisher = {Walter de Gruyter},
  location = {Berlin},
  date = {1968},
  pages = {165--485},
}
```