# Bibtex, how to define our own citation key instead of 'author date '

Tags: bibtex

I try to find a bibtex style with abbreviation (such `alpha`) but with my own citation key.
This link (http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html) give a large list of style but none is what I search.

Now I have such entry in my `biblio.bib`

```
@book{cormen,
author = {Thomas Cormen and others},
...
year = {2004},
}
@book{bac2,
author = {Marc Des},
...
year = {2011},
}
```

And I get such keys : `[C+04]` and `[des11]` but they are not very relevant in the text. I try to have something more natural to read such as "... see chap. 2 in [Bac2] ..."

Is it possible to set my own abbreviation to have (or to set) something like `[Cormen]` and `[Bac2]` (without date) ?

Comment: The first entry is wrong: it should be `Thomas Cormen and others`. I don't know of any bib style where you can specify an arbitrary citation label.

Comment: What you are asking for is against the widely accepted standards. If you publish a paper like that, it may contribute to a negative peer review.

Comment: @ADP I use latex to write memento's. That's the meaning to have somethings easy to read. Nobody else is going to change the sources of my document even though I share my final work (the pdf) with some other students ;-)

Comment: I read something about biblatex instead of bibtex but I can't use it ! It doesn't compile ('aux' file not found) with my Texniccenter

Comment: You can have your own citation key using `biblatex`, see the manual, or [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49265/21591).

Comment: @ mafp : thx but as already said, the tries with biblatex fails ! And during this blocus period i have not time enought to investigate more

Comment: For hand tuning certain labels, [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91428/21591) might be helpful.